# Sunspot not working properly in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot-rails

I am using following gems

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

In model, I have also mention and I have also reindex the sunspot all have been tried but don't know what is the issue that its not returning any result:

```
searchable do
  text :email
end
```

for searching, when I follow its documentation all is working fine, no error but there is no result. Also it always return a output like this:

```
<Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:User"], :q=>"talentuser1", :fl=>"* score", :qf=>"email_text", :defType
=>"edismax", :start=>0, :rows=>30}>
```

if anyone have faced this type of problem then please help me out of this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, first we should configure SOLR, example(Inside Post model):

```
searchable do
  integer :blog_id
  integer :category_id
end

self.search(options) do
  any_of do
    with(:blog_id, options[:blog_id])
    with(:category_id, options[:category_id])
  end
end
```

Then, we have to do `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`
Then, to get the results

```
post = Post.search(:blog_id => 1, :category_id => 2)
results = post.results
```

These steps should give you your search result

Comment: Brother, I have already did that just like:

searchable do
    text :email
  end

Comment: @user3436543 Are you re-indexing after that? And, the output you have mentioned in the question, is standard solr output, the only thing that needs to be done is to fetch the results

Comment: Yes i did, and i am tring to fetch record the records its shows nil but there is record in a table

Comment: This looks like a re-indexing problem to me, try restarting solr `rake sunspot:solr:stop` then `rake sunspot:solr:start` and re-indexing it `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

Comment: Hey brother, its working fine actually there is no issue just restart my PC its working fine but can you help me that how can we fetch multiple records because when i am searching its relate with User Id but i want to search on basis on particular filed for all user not particular one

Comment: Can you ask the question in a separate thread with all details and post the link